# Can this particular recursion be rewritten in a tail-optimized way?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

```
phi n 0 = 1
phi n l = 1 + 1 / phi n (l - 1)
```

Obviously, the last evaluated action **is not** recursive call, thus given implementation indeed throws with a sufficiently large `l`.

So what's the way (if any) to rewrite recursion such that 1) it remains recursive, 2) becomes tail-optimized? I assume `phi n l result` would work, however can't redefine accordingly... are there reliable methods/techniques how to tackle down such a problems?

Comment: The most common approach in Haskell would be to rewrite it with productive corecursion instead of tail-calls. That's just almost always better in Haskell. Is there some reason that doesn't work in your use case?

Comment: @Carl, I am not haskeller. Can you please show how it gonna look like?

Comment: The productive corecursion version would look something like `phiApproximations = iterate (\x -> 1 + (1/x)) 1`, but it's probably worth using something stricter than `iterate` there. The basic idea is to set up the calculation such that you generate successive results hidden behind data constructors so that they're only calculated if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have this computation tree:

```
               +                 l
              ╱ ╲
             1   ÷
                ╱ ╲
               1   +             l-1
                  ╱ ╲
                 1   ÷
                    ╱ ╲
                   1  ...
                        ╲
                         +       1
                        ╱ ╲
                       1   ÷
                          ╱ ╲
                         1   1   0
```

Since this has a linear shape, you can indeed make it tail-recursive. For this you need to start at the bottom and keep the already-calculated right result in an accumulator variable.

```
phi _ l = go 0 1  -- n isn't actually used
 where go l' acc
        | l' < l     = go (l'+1) $! 1 + 1/acc
        | otherwise  = acc
```

Not tested, there might be an off-by-1 error here.

Comment: Always make your accumulator strict!  `$` ⟼ `$!`

Comment: why so? to prevent memory leak due to native Haskell's laziness?

Comment: Basically, yes. If the accumulator isn't strict, then haskell will just build a potentially large thunk, and in the case of most accumulators, the thunk is more memory-costly than the actual value(for instance, with `Int32` accumulator, it's just 4 bytes, vs much more for a thunk). An example of that is using `foldl' (+) 0` to sum large lists of numbers instead of `foldl (+) 0`. (The former is strict in the accumulator)

Comment: Speaking of strictness, `BangPatterns` are pretty common for strict accumulators: `go l' !acc | l' < l = go (l' + 1) (1 + 1 / acc) | otherwise = acc`—a little bit simpler than `seq` or `$!`, although less explicit.